# I need a function to display an 'unprocessed' expression

Tags: scheme

I am new to Scheme so excuse me if I am using the wrong vocabulary. I want a function, I am calling it QandA, that will (among other things) display its raw or unprocessed argument. For example:

```
 (QandA (+ 1 2)) should return the string "(+ 1 2) : 3" 
 (QandA (quote (+ 1 2))) should return "(quote (+ 1 2)) : (+ 1 2)"
```

What I first tried was:

```
 (define (QandA x)
   (display (quote x)) (display " : " ) (display x))
```

but then

```
 (QandA (+ 1 2)) returns "x : 3"
```

I understand why this is wrong, but don't know where to look to find a solution.

So the question is, what do I replace (display (quote x)) with to get the behavior I require. Any hints welcome.

Comment: For this question, it's rather relevant to know which interpreter you're using. Please add the appropriate tag ;)

Comment: I am using Dr Racket, but use #lang scheme which (correct me if I am wrong) should make things scheme-like. My preference would be for a solution that is 'pure' scheme (if any such thing exists).

Comment: My solution will work using `#lang scheme`, but it's not standard Scheme. Using only standard procedures, it'll be messy to convert the value of the expression into a string (because we don't know beforehand what will that be). Of course, if you only need to _display_ the answer, then @ymonad's answer works fine.

Comment: And by the way, [here](http://racket-lang.org/new-name.html)'s some clarification regarding `#lang scheme`. For a standards-based Scheme you should use `#lang r6rs` … and you'll find some limitations, compared to Racket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ymonad pointed out, this is a good scenario for using [macros](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/macros.html) - because you need to defer the evaluation of the expression that's passed as parameter to `QandA`. Some of your previous questions were tagged `racket`, so here's an implementation for Racket using `#lang racket` (also works for `#lang scheme`) that returns a *string*, as requested (if you want to *display* the value replace `format` with `printf`):

```
(define-syntax-rule (QandA exp)
  (format "~a : ~a" 'exp exp))
```

This is the output for the sample input given in the question:

```
(QandA (+ 1 2))
=> "(+ 1 2) : 3"

(QandA (quote (+ 1 2)))
=> "(quote (+ 1 2)) : (+ 1 2)"
```

Comment: If we're talking about Racket, go straight for `define-syntax-rule` in this case. :-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Yep, that's simpler. Got it!

Answer (score 1):

As you see, you cannot achieve it using function since the argument is evaluated before it is passed to the function.

One solution is using [macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Defining-Macros.html), it can access to the unprocessed expression and create another expression.

Here's an example that works on [guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/)

```
(define-syntax QandA
 (syntax-rules ()
  ((QandA arg)
   (begin (display (quote arg))(display " : ")(display arg)))))

(QandA ((+ 1 2))) ; (+ 1 2) : 3
(QandA (quote (+ 1 2))) ; (quote (+ 1 2)) : (+ 1 2)
```

The supported syntax of generating macro differs by interpreters, so you should check the document of interpreter which you are using.
However, `define-syntax` and `syntax-rules` should be able to use in interpreter which supports [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-8.html#%_sec_5.3) or [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.2.2).

Comment: `syntax-rules` has been standard since R5RS, and it's expected to stay standardised "forever". I would consider any Scheme that lacks `syntax-rules` support to be broken. In other words, I don't consider `syntax-rules` to "differ by interpreter".

Comment: Sorry, what I mean that "differ by interpreter", is that there might be more convenient syntax such as `define-syntax-rule` in Racket, which is not always supported in other interpreters, so check the document and use it if possible. Yes, most of the recent scheme implementation supports at least `R5RS`.